# Setup scheduler / cron in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I make my first cron in larval.
I use Laravel 9.
I need automated run my application via cron.

I tried it in Laravel using scheduler (use larval good practices).

I have this code:

Command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

//API pogodowe
use Cmfcmf\OpenWeatherMap;
use Cmfcmf\OpenWeatherMap\Exception as OWMException;

//dostęp do pamięci cache
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

//biblioteka narzędzi date/time
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class getWeather extends Command {

    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'getWeather:current'; //tak będzie wywoływana komenda z CLI (artisan command)

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Pobiera bieżące dane pogodowe.'; //opis komendy 

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle() { 

        $lang = 'pl'; 
        $units = 'metric';

        //tworzymy obiekt OpenWeatherMap z naszym kluczem API
        $owm = new OpenWeatherMap(config('constants.OPENWEATHER_API_KEY'));

        //czy w cache są poprzednie dane? jeżeli tak, to pobieramy
        $pogoda = Cache::has('pogoda') ? Cache::get('pogoda') : array(); 

        // Stan powietrza
        $data = @file_get_contents("http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/aqindex/getIndex/config('constants.ID_STACJI_POMIAROWEJ')"); //pobieramy dane z serera GIOS
        if ($data) {
            $air = json_decode($data); //poszło OK, dekodujemy do obiektu
        } else { //uwaliło się, poinformujmy o tym w logu
            $air = null;
            echo Carbon::now() . "\t" . 'Bład pobierania danych o stanie powietrza' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        // Dane pogodowe
        try {
            $current = $owm->getWeather(config('constants.OPENWEATHER_CITY_ID'), $units, $lang); //pobieramy aktualne dane dla miasta z id=OPENWEATHER_CITY_ID
            $forecast = $owm->getDailyWeatherForecast(config('constants.OPENWEATHER_CITY_ID'), $units, $lang, '', 2); //pobieramy prognozę na dwa najbliższe dni dla miasta z id=OPENWEATHER_CITY_ID
        } catch (OWMException $e) { //lipa, coś się nie udało
            echo Carbon::now() . "\t" . 'OpenWeatherMap exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' (Code ' . $e->getCode() . ').' . PHP_EOL;
        } catch (Exception $e) { //lipa, ale poważniejsza
            echo Carbon::now() . "\t" . 'General exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' (Code ' . $e->getCode() . ').' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        if ($current) { //mamy to! sprawdzamy aktualną pogodę
            // Dzisiaj
            if (@getimagesize('http:' . $current->weather->getIconURL())) { //sztuczka magiczna - sprawdzam, czy dostarczona nazwa pliku ikony jest powiązana z fizycznym plikiem
                $pogoda['today'] = $current; //uff, wszytsko jest ok, zapisujemy w tablicy
            }
        }

        if ($forecast) { //mamy to! sprawdzamy prognozę na jutro
            $forecast->rewind(); //ustawiamy na dzisiaj
            $forecast->next(); //ustawiamy na kolejnej pozycji (jutro)
            $tommorow = $forecast->current(); //pobieramy jutrzejsze dane
            // dalej to samo, co powyżej
            if (@getimagesize('http:' . $tommorow->weather->getIconURL())) {
                $pogoda['tommorow'] = $tommorow;
            }
        }

        // Stan powietrza
        if ($air && $air->stIndexLevel->id >= 0) { // ignorujemy dla id<0 - to oznacza brak danych
            $pogoda['air'] = $air;
        }

        // Dane do cache
        Cache::forget('pogoda'); //usuwamy poprzednie
        Cache::forever('pogoda', $pogoda); //nowe zapisujemy na zawsze

    }

}
```

and app/Console/kernel.php:

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        '\App\Console\Commands\getWeather', //to nasza nowa komenda 
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('getWeather:current') // i od teraz chcemy, żeby
                ->everyThirtyMinutes() // była uruchamina co 30 minut
                ->appendOutputTo('/var/log/scheduled_weather.log') //a komunikaty zapisywała w pliku dziennika;
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

I want to run this code in: every Monday, Thursday and Saturday at midnight.

How can I make it work ?

Comment: You've posted a load of code here and asked about CRON. Is your problem setting up a CRON job, or making CRON run this code, or some problem in this code when it runs with CRON?

Answer (score 0):

Use the function days that get in parameters an array of days

(Sundays=0, mondays=1, thursdays=4, saturdays=6)

you can also append the time at which you want to execute the cron.

For more information, you can check the task scheduling details here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling

```
$schedule->command('getWeather:current')->weekly()->days([1,4,6])->at('00:01');
```